# jcifs fails to resolve a DFS url

Tags: samba, jcifs, microsoft-distributed-file-system

When trying to access an SmbFile with a DFS URL, the jcifs library fails. But when I use the UNC returned by `dfsutil` it works.

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication( domain, user, pass );
SmbFile folder = new SmbFile(path,auth);
```

If `path` is set to

```
smb://mydomain.example.com/ourdfs/go/to/my/folder
```

the call fails with

```
Exception in thread "main" jcifs.smb.SmbException: The network name cannot be found.
```

But it is successful when invoked with the resolved name

```
dfsutil diag viewdfspath \\mydomain.example.com\ourdfs\go\to\my\folder

The DFS Path <\\mydomain.example.com\ourdfs\go\to\my\folder> 
resolves to -> <\\someserver.example.com\sharename$\my\folder>
```

Then the following url works for `path`

```
smb://someserver.example.com/sharename$/my/folder
```

How do I set up jcifs to handle DFS properly i.e. not having to translate urls thru `dfsutil`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the WINS configuration. `IPCONFIG /ALL` will show the information:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : MYDOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Ethernet Connection
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : DE-AD-BE-EF-F0-0D
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.1.42(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : December 3, 2018 09:03:04 AM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : December 9, 2018 09:03:04 AM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.1.1
DHCPv4 Class ID . . . . . . . . . : O-mobile
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.11.13
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.4.48
                                    10.10.4.56
Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 10.10.1.59
Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 10.10.2.58
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

The then configuration item has to be set as follows:

```
jcifs.netbios.wins=10.10.1.59
```

or by setting it with `jcifs.Config.setProperty()`